# Other ways of checking if a class has a certain member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

Let's check if

```
struct Thing {
    int foo(double, bool) {return 0;}
};
```

has the `int foo(double, bool)` member function during compile time.  There are many ways of doing this, and most are just variations of others.  Can someone think of a way that is vastly different (or at least fairly creative) than the 5 ways I mention here?  I'm just trying to learn some new techniques with templates and SFINAE.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Using void_t (this includes using std::is_detected).
template <typename T>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_foo : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_foo<T,
        void_t<decltype(static_cast<int>(std::declval<T>().foo(double{}, bool{})))>
    > : std::true_type {};

// Using the ... default argument.
template <typename T>
struct hasfoo {
    template <typename U>
    static std::true_type test (decltype(static_cast<int(T::*)(double, bool)>(&T::foo))*);  // or 'decltype(static_cast<int>(std::declval<U>().foo(double{}, bool{})))*' works fine too.

    template <typename>
    static std::false_type test (...);

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(nullptr))::value;
};

// Overloads and trailing return types.
template <typename>
struct Helper : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
auto helper(int) -> Helper<decltype(static_cast<int>(std::declval<T>().foo(double{}, bool{})))>;

template <typename>
std::false_type helper(long);

template <typename T>
constexpr bool hasFoo() {return decltype(helper<T>(0))::value;}

// Comma operator (basically the same as the above).
template <typename T>
auto check(int) -> decltype(static_cast<int>(std::declval<T>().foo(double{}, bool{})), std::true_type{});

template <typename T>
std::false_type check(...);

template <typename T>
using HasFoo = decltype(check<T>(0));

// Member function pointer template parameter.
template <typename T>
struct Hasfoo {
    template <typename U, int(U::*)(double, bool)>
    struct Tag;

    template <typename U>
    static constexpr bool test (Tag<U, &U::foo>*) {return true;}

    template <typename>
    static constexpr bool test (...) {return false;}

    static constexpr bool value = test<T>(nullptr);
};

// Tests
struct Thing {
    int foo(double, bool) {return 0;}
};

int main() {
    static_assert (has_foo<Thing>::value, "");
    static_assert (hasfoo<Thing>::value, "");
    static_assert (hasFoo<Thing>(), "");
    static_assert (HasFoo<Thing>::value, "");
}
```

Edit:  I just remembered an elegant and more general solution that Yakk gave to a different question quite a while ago (here is his actual typing, modified only to match the foo function):

```
namespace meta {
  namespace details {
    template<template<class...>class Z, class=void, class...Ts>
    struct can_apply : std::false_type {};
    template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
    struct can_apply<Z, decltype((void)(std::declval<Z<Ts...>>())), Ts...>:
      std::true_type
    {};
  }
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;
}

template<class T>
using member_foo = decltype(static_cast<int(T::*)(double, bool)>(&T::foo));

template<class T>
using has_member_foo = meta::can_apply<member_foo, T>;
```

Comment: Of the four options listed, only `hasfoo` will detect a change from `int foo(double,bool) { return 0; }` to `int foo(double,double) { return 0; }` for example.

Comment: Hmm... I guess I'm not caring too much about implicit conversions.  But `decltype(static_cast<int(T::*)(double, bool)>(&T::foo))*` could be used for all of them then.  It's what surrounds that expression that I'm curious about.

Comment: `template<class T> concept bool foo_double_bool = requires (T t) { t.foo(0.0, true); };`. How many different ways of saying the same thing do you need?

Comment: @T.C. concepts have not been invited to the party yet :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone think of a way that is vastly different (or at least fairly creative) than the 5 ways I mention here?

A fairly creative way to do that could be the one below.
It is based on the `sizeof` operator and a trivial *using declaration* (here named `Type`).
SFINAE and partial template specialization do the rest.

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<cstddef>

template<typename T, std::size_t>
using Type = T;

template<typename T, typename = T>
struct U: std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct U<T, Type<T, sizeof(static_cast<void(T::*)(int)>(&T::f))>>: std::true_type {};

struct S { void f(int) {} };
struct R { int f(double) { return 42; } };
struct T {};

int main() {
    static_assert(U<S>::value, "!");
    static_assert(not U<R>::value, "!");
    static_assert(not U<T>::value, "!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone think of a way that is vastly different (or at least fairly creative) than the 5 ways I mention here?

A fairly creative way to do that could be the one below.
It is based on the `noexcept` operator and a trivial *using declaration* (here named `Type`).
SFINAE and partial template specialization do the rest.

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

template<typename T, bool>
using Type = T;

template<typename T, typename = T>
struct U: std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct U<T, Type<T, noexcept(std::declval<T>().f(42))>>: std::true_type {};

struct S { void f(int) {} };
struct T {};

int main() {
    static_assert(U<S>::value, "!");
    static_assert(not U<T>::value, "!");
}
```

This solution has a *problem* if compared to the others.
As an example, the struct below would pass the test as well:

```
struct R { int f(double) {} };
```

In other terms, as long as the function to be tested accepts one argument to the type of which 42 can be cast and no matter what's the return type, it is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone think of a way that is vastly different (or at least fairly creative) than the 5 ways I mention here?

A fairly creative way to do that could be the one below.
It doesn't exploit any unevaluated context. Instead, it relies on a trivial *using declaration* (here named `Type`) and that's all.
SFINAE and partial template specialization do the rest.

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T, void(T::*)(int)>
using Type = T;

template<typename T, typename = T>
struct U: std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct U<T, Type<T, &T::f>>: std::true_type {};

struct S { void f(int) {} };
struct R { int f(double) { return 42; } };
struct T {};

int main() {
    static_assert(U<S>::value, "!");
    static_assert(not U<R>::value, "!");
    static_assert(not U<T>::value, "!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone think of a way that is vastly different (or at least fairly creative) than the 5 ways I mention here?

A fairly creative way to do that could be the one below.
It is based on function template and overloading. If you know how tag dispatching works, it should be pretty straightforward to understand.

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<cstddef>

template<typename T, void(T::*)(int) = &T::f>
constexpr std::true_type f(int) { return {}; }

template<typename T>
constexpr std::false_type f(char) { return {}; }

template<typename T>
constexpr auto detect() { return f<T>(0); }

struct S { void f(int) {} };
struct R { int f(double) { return 42; } };
struct T {};

int main() {
    static_assert(detect<S>(), "!");
    static_assert(not detect<R>(), "!");
    static_assert(not detect<T>(), "!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone think of a way that is vastly different (or at least fairly creative) than the 5 ways I mention here?

If you can use C++14, another way of check if a class has a member variable is by means if template variables.
As an example:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
constexpr bool has_foo = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_foo<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().foo(), void())> = true;
```

I guess it's probably one of the more compact solution at least.

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<utility>

template<typename T, typename = void>
constexpr bool has_f = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_f<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().f(0), void())> = true;

struct S { void f(int) {} };
struct T {};

int main() {
    static_assert(has_f<S>, "!");
    static_assert(not has_f<T>, "!");
}
```